# How to get the MAX Value In Quantity_by_Category?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductCategory, SUM(pd.Quantity) AS Quantity_by_Category 
FROM Purchase_Details pd 
INNER JOIN Products p
ON pd.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY pd.ProductID
ORDER BY p.ProductID;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrb6P.png)

Comment: what does the query in the question refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done with aggregate function MAX() using your query as a subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(Quantity_by_Category)
FROM (your_query) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put order by to Quantity_by_Category desc

Comment: Haaa! Thanks Bro, Its very simple to do, but i do more complicated to solve this. your answer is also correct